# Get offset/position of bytes written to file

Tags: go

I'm writing a string to a file, and I'd like to get the offset of the string which was just written.
Here is the code writing the file:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func main() {
    path := "test_file.txt"
    byteString := []byte("string to write")

    f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    if _, err = f.Write(byteString); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

How can I get the offset after having written the line ?

Comment: Maybe `f.Seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR) - len(byteString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.Write` only returns the length of the bytes written. If you want the offset, you can either:

1. Call `os.Stat` before writing, and then use `os.WriteAt` to write at the offset for the end of the file provided by the `FileInfo` structure.
2. Call `os.Stat` after writing, and subtract the length written to the file from the new size.

Comment: I've used the second option, works like a charm thanks.
However, would you recommend any of your solution over the other ? If yes, why ?